# TortoiseGit log not showing all expected commit messages in some environments

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

Last week, I merged two git repositories into one, new repository following the steps outlined [in this blog](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/). To the best of my knowledge this all went smoothly. All files exist. I am able to find all commits by their SHA.

Now, I am inspecting the log history for a single file using TortoiseGit. I have "follow renames" enabled. When I view the history I do not see any commit messages for any of the branches I transitioned to the new repository, but I do see all commit messages for older branches:

[image]

When I run `gitk --follow User.cs` I am able to see the commit messages as expected:

[image]

Steps I've taken to try and solve:

- Update Git to latest: 2.10.2.windows.1
- Reinstall TortoiseGit. It was already the latest version: 2.3.0
- Delete the repository and pull it again.
- Went to TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Saved Data and cleared all.
- Looked for bug report on TortoiseGit Gitlab issue tracker. I did not find anything.

This issue occurs on two of my machines. Both machines were used when merging the two repositories. None of my coworkers experience this issue. They did not use their PCs to assist in merging the repositories.

**Question:** Is anyone aware of any other caches, settings, or other configuration options I should consider to repair my TortoiseGit instances?

For reference, the steps outlined in the blog are:

```
# Assume the current directory is where we want the new repository to be created
# Create the new repository
git init

# Before we do a merge, we have to have an initial commit, so we’ll make a dummy commit
dir > deleteme.txt
git add .
git commit -m “Initial dummy commit”

# Add a remote for and fetch the old repo
git remote add -f old_a <OldA repo URL>

# Merge the files from old_a/master into new/master
git merge old_a/master

# Clean up our dummy file because we don’t need it any more
git rm .\deleteme.txt
git commit -m “Clean up initial file”

# Move the old_a repo files and folders into a subdirectory so they don’t collide with the other repo coming later
mkdir old_a
dir –exclude old_a | %{git mv $_.Name old_a}

# Commit the move
git commit -m “Move old_a files into subdir”

# Do the same thing for old_b
git remote add -f old_b <OldB repo URL>
git merge old_b/master
mkdir old_b
dir –exclude old_a,old_b | %{git mv $_.Name old_b}
git commit -m “Move old_b files into subdir”

##########################

# Bring over a feature branch from one of the old repos
git checkout -b feature-in-progress
git merge -s recursive -Xsubtree=old_a old_a/feature-in-progress
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try to select **All Branches** above the refresh button (left-bottom) from the first picture what you shared. And you will find all the branches and commit histories.

Comment: You can't enable "All Branches" when "Follow Renames" is checked. You'll note in the screenshot that the checkbox for "All Branches" is grayed out.

Comment: @SeanAnderson So it seems your OS is not windows, it’s Linux or something. I use git bash on windows so I just manually move files into old_A or old_B instead of using `dir –exclude old_a | %{git mv $_.Name old_a}` or `dir –exclude old_a,old_b | %{git mv $_.Name old_b}`. After those steps in blog, I use TortoiseGit in the new repo directory, everything as expected and the All Branches can be selected.